# How to toggle between SVG images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two SVG image files. When I click on an image another image must be displayed (similar to tab). I tried it with the following:

```js
jQuery("#infoToggler").click(function() {
  jQuery(this).find('img').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="infoToggler">
  <img src="http://tympanus.net/PausePlay/images/play.png" width="60px" height="60px" />
  <img src="http://maraa.in/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/pause-in-times-of-conflict.png" width="60px" height="60px" style="display:none" />
</div>
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/M9QBb/91/)

This is not working. Could someone please help me?

**Edit 01**

```
<html>
<head>

    .image{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    z-index:1;
    }
    .image1{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    z-index:1;
    }
    .image3{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    z-index:1;
    }
    .image4{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    z-index:1;
    }
</head>
<body>
<img src="image1.svg" class="image"/>
<img src="image2.svg" class="image1"/>
<img src="image3.svg" class="image2"/>
<img src="image4.svg" class="image3"/>
</body>
</html>
```

These are 4 class I have in CSS. I need to display 2 image and toggle 2 image separately.Like tab menu when I click one tab image must toggle and if i click another tab that must toggle. When I click `image1` then `image2` must be displayed and if I click `image3` then `image4` must be displayed

Comment: works fine ... do you get any errors n your console?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jn0bpevc/1/ works fine

Comment: lol whoever edit the question, please check back what you have done to link..it was working before..

Comment: added the link
Thanks :)

Comment: Works for me as well.

Comment: This works fine for me. How to have many image like tab bar menu when I click It should become active and inactive respectively.For that I am having 2 images

Comment: @SundarNivash Please avoid follow-up questions in comments. If you have a _specific and reproducible_ problem, [edit] your question to include a full example of your _non-working_ code. So far, it isn’t clear _what_ doesn’t work, _how_ it doesn’t work, _what you actually want_ and _which of your own attempts_ didn’t work.

Comment: I have edited my question please verify it..@Xufox

Comment: You should probably include the HTML as well.

Comment: I have just added it please kindly verify it...@Xufox

Answer (score -1):

I have created jsfiddle sample.

[Visit SVG image toggle jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/viratpatel/hcpbwwza/)

```
$("#svgImg").on("click", function() {
    if(flag) {
        $(this).attr("xlink:href", "http://maraa.in/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/pause-in-times-of-conflict.png");
        flag = false;
    }
    else {
        $(this).attr("xlink:href", "http://tympanus.net/PausePlay/images/play.png");
        flag = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your support. Now i need Tab menu like structure